# ASP.NET MVC3 - How to route to/direct user to .HTML files

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm porting a web forms application to MVC 3.  A majority of the files are .HTML files.  Ignoring the option of converting these to views, how can I route [?] to HTML files?

Comment: what do you mean? you can just link to them.

Answer (score 2):

You just reference them like any other content file. Just keep them out of the named folders (Areas, Models, Repositories, Controllers, Views, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Look in you Global.asax and add an ignore:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.html/{*pathInfo}");  // add this
```

and be a little careful with where you put them. The root and /contents should be fine.

Comment: I don't think this is needed for files that exist on the disk. http://haacked.com/archive/2008/07/14/make-routing-ignore-requests-for-a-file-extension.aspx

Comment: @BNL - probably right, especially when you avoid folders that could be confused with Controllers. I meant it as a way to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to modify the routes table, put them in the Content folder and reference them like you would any content file.

```
<a href='@Url.Content("~/Content/path/to/file.html")'>Your html file</a>
```